# Configure jboss AS7 to use multiple modules dirs

Tags: module, jboss7.x

Is it possible (and if: how?) to set up JBoss AS7 to use his own modules dir and an additional custom modules.custom at the same time? If so, I would not have to mix my custom entries with the default entries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do that by setting **JBOSS_MODULEPATH** env variable to include more than just your folder.
For instance configuration like this

```
set JBOSS_MODULEPATH=%JBOSS_HOME%/modules;/path/to/my/modules
```

it would add /path/to/my/modules to path of modules. But just make sure you still keep default folder in your module path.

for more you can take a look at standalone.sh/bat and look how this variable is used.

(if you are on mac or unix, use export and colons)

```
export JBOSS_MODULPATH=$JBOSS_HOME/modules:/path/to/my/modules
```

Comment: Pay attention to the colon : between module paths for unix systems (instead of the semicolon ;). I lost hours to figure out why it wasn't working :/

Comment: Note that the letter e is missing missing in the JBOSS_MODULEPATH key in the linux config line above.  Tried to edit it but the edit changed too few characters.